# Proportionate Columns in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does bootstrap have a way to specify justified columns, in the same way that I could do with tables? In other words, I know I want six columns across, but using span2 will give me six equal columns. But this will look inconsistent because some of my columns have less text than others, and I want them equally spaced.

If I resorted to tables and didn't specify column widths, it would distribute each column width proportionately, giving me the exact effect I'm looking for.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand.. `span2` does provide 6 evenly spaced, equal width columns.. can you post the code you've tried, or an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @ Heraldmonkey: The world of web design and development would be way too easy if this was possible.

Comment: @Skelly I've updated my original post to more clearly describe what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. Not unless you want to tweak the grid yourself. Having a `span2` column that has less width than other `span2` columns breaks the layout and defeats the point.

One possibility is to create an inner div inside the column and give it either padding or margins to make its content area smaller.

Otherwise, just roll your own grid and use that instead. It's fairly easy.